# Почему не меняется цвет текста MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Почему цвет текста не меняется?
Создал цветовую тему:

```
 const theme = createTheme({
    
    palette: {
      botam: {
        main: '#9D9D9D'
      },
      tehs: {
        main: '#FFFF'
      }
  }});
```

Указал параметры у Typography:

```
<Typography theme={theme} variant='h8' colors="tehs">

  Добрый день

</Typography>
```

Comment: Может нужно `colors="tehs.main"`?

Comment: Всё равно не меняется

Comment: Может вам нужно обернуть компоненты в `ThemeProvider`?

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось.